# Add my own onclick function with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I want to add a button, with an onclick event, to the page. It will eventually open an overlay div.

But, I can't get even an alert running.

I've used a couple of techniques, like `unsafeWindow`, and adding the script tags to the body, but still doesn't work.

This is the code that I'm using right now:

```
function main() {
    var script_source = '<script type="text/javascript">function doenwedan(){alert("hebben we gedaan!");}</script>';
    var link_knop = '<br /><br /><br /><br /><button onclick="doenwedan()" value="gaan we doen">gaan we doen</button>';
    var orginele_pagina = document.getElementById('ds_body').innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('ds_body').innerHTML =orginele_pagina + link_knop + script_source ;
}

main();
```

How can I get this working?
I need a technique like this, because when the overlay div is called, there will be new functions needed, so if got to inject them then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several things:

1. Don't inject JS if you don't have to (On the Evil Overlord list next to "Don't turn into a snake; it never helps").
2. Don't futz with `innerHTML` if you don't have to.  It busts things and leads to the temptation of trying to regex HTML.
3. Use DOM methods to add things, with rare exceptions.
4. I'm not sure that a script node, created thus, will be parsed anyway.
5. Might as well start using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  It makes things simpler and more robust.

Putting it all together, your script would become something like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Add a button
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

function doenwedan () {
    alert ("hebben we gedaan!");
}

var orginele_pagina = $('#ds_body');
orginele_pagina.append (
    '<br><br><br><br><button id="myButton" value="gaan we doen">gaan we doen</button>'
);

$("#myButton").click (doenwedan);
```

Comment: jQuery (and therefore) your piece of script lookes like it doesn't work :S I get no button at all right now...

Comment: The script works perfectly (as long as you set the `@include` correctly), I just double checked.   You're going to have to be clear and specific about how it "doesn't work". Verify the following: (1) You are not using Greasemonkey version 0.9.14, (2) In your Firefox user profile, in the `gm_scripts` folder for your script, the file `jquerymin.js` exists, (3) The really is a node on the page with the **id** "ds_body", (4) That node is NOT added via AJAX.

Comment: (1) I'm using verion 0.9.15. (2) i require it on this way: // @require   http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js  (3)That node realy excist. (4) That node is part of the body (the id of the body tag), so i ashume it's not added with ajax...

Comment: Re item (2), that's not what I asked (and also not per the answer!).  Go to [the Firefox profile directory](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox), find the `gm_scripts` folder, then find the folder for your script.  Verify that `jquerymin.js` exists in that folder. ... If you still can't get the script to work for you, **Link to the Target Page**.

Comment: Hy, the jquery min is now in the containing folder. And there was something else strange... Because my script wasn't on the list anymore. Now it's working. thanks for the help ;P